# How to create moving image from right to left with reverse using react-spring?

Tags: reactjs, animation, jsx, react-spring, react-animations

Can someone help me with my propblem? I need to make animation with png image on my react project. My img must moving from right to left in own block with reverse in the end of the right side and left side. I made a part of  my code, but cann't understand how to  make reverse? I use react-spring.
const [key, setKey] = useState(1);

```
const styles = useSpring({
    from: { transform: "translate(50%,0)" },
    to: { transform: "translate(-50%,0)" },
    config: { duration: 4000 },
    reset: true,
    reverse: key % 2 == 0,
    onRest: () => {
        setKey(key + 1);
      }
})
```

return

<animated.img img className={classes.fishPicture} style={styles} src={fishOne} alt="fish"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array version of the `to` key take the animation back to the original location and then combine that with `loop: true`

```
  const styles = useSpring({
    from: { transform: "translate(50%,0)" },
    to: [{ transform: "translate(-50%,0)" }, { transform: "translate(50%,0)" }],
    config: { duration: 500 },
    loop: true
  });
```

Here is a working example I created: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-looping-tranform-animation-tgb7z

Comment: Can I make this animation like random in block?

Comment: What do you mean by random in block?

Comment: I mean random way of animation. Not only two ways. Can I make it with this library?

Comment: Ah. I just update the sandbox to move the box randomly. The key here is passing a function as the to key in the spring.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are the best)